# How to trigger function in Vue when dropdown option selected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want a function to be called using Vue when a user selects an option from a dropdown list. I've started with a really simple example, but i can't seem to get it to work. I have no console errors or errors highlighted in WebStorm, so i'm unsure where i'm going wrong.

Here's my code:

```
<template>
    <b-container>
        <b-row>
            <b-col>
                <div>
                    <b-dropdown id="ddown4" text="Product Type" class="m-md-2" v-on:change="FilterProduct">
                        <b-dropdown-item>4.5</b-dropdown-item>
                        <b-dropdown-item>10.5</b-dropdown-item>
                    </b-dropdown>
                </div>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: 'ProductFilters',
        methods:{
            FilterProduct(){
                alert('Yes!');
            }

        },
        data() {
            return {
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're listening for a native DOM event (one that is emitted by a regular HTML element, such as a `select` element, not a Vue component), you'll need to use the [.native modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) ..

```
<b-dropdown id="ddown4" text="Product Type" class="m-md-2" v-on:change.native="FilterProduct">
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and for directing me to .native, i hadn't seen that before, however this still isn't working for me.

Comment: @user3005003 It should work if the HTML element emitting the `change` event is the root element of your component. If not you'll need to use `v-on="$listeners"` on that element. You can read up on that [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components).

Comment: @user3005003 Another option would be to `$emit` a custom `change` event by your `select` element like this `<select @change="$emit('change')" ...>`.